# Javafx ComboBox disappearing items after select

Tags: image, list, combobox, javafx, icons

I have created a (JavaFX) **combobox**, which I am populating with an observable list made from **HBoxes**, so that I can display an image with some text in each list cell.

This displays well, other than the fact that whenever you select one of the items in the list, it will disappear. Once you have selected every item, it will not render any items at all. (You can still select them by clicking in the space where they previously were.

Do you know how I might correct this, please?

[image] [image]

**Part of my code is displayed below:**

```
public class IconListComboBox {

Group listRoot = new Group();
VBox mainVBox = new VBox();
ComboBox selectionBox = new ComboBox();
List<HBox> list = new ArrayList<HBox>();
ListView<HBox> listView = new ListView<HBox>();
ObservableList<HBox> observableList;



public IconListComboBox(int dimensionX, int dimensionY, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<ImageView> icons)
{

    //VBox.setVgrow(list, Priority.ALWAYS);
    selectionBox.setPrefWidth(dimensionY);
    selectionBox.setPrefHeight(40);

    for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        HBox cell = new HBox();
        Label name = new Label(names.get(i));
        Label icon = new Label();
        icon.setGraphic(icons.get(i));
        name.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        icon.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        icon.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(icon, Priority.ALWAYS);
        cell.getChildren().add(icon);
        cell.getChildren().add(name);
        list.add(cell);


    }

    observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
    listView.setItems(observableList);

    listView.setPrefWidth(dimensionX);
    selectionBox.setMaxWidth(dimensionX);
    listView.setMaxWidth(dimensionX);

    selectionBox.setItems(observableList);

    mainVBox.getChildren().add(selectionBox);
    mainVBox.getChildren().add(listRoot);
    //mainVBox.getChildren().add(listView);
    //listRoot.getChildren().add(listView);


}
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly the example cited in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) under "A warning about inserting Nodes into the ComboBox items list".

The list of items in the combo box should represent data - not the UI component used to display the data. The issue is that the `HBox` cannot appear twice in the scene graph: so it cannot appear both in the "selected cell" and as a cell in the drop-down list.

Instead, create a class that represents the data you are displaying in the `ComboBox`, and use a cell factory to instruct the `ComboBox` as to how to display those data. Be sure to set a button cell as well (the cell used for the selected item).

Comment: Thank you @James_D, this does help. I had already seen this in the documentation, but didn't quite understand how .setCellFactory works, and still don't. I shall have to look into it. Would I be able to do something along the lines of: `.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<HBox>, ListCell<HBox>>()` ... ?

Comment: More or less, but you will have to change the type of the `ComboBox` form `HBox` to the class you use to represent your data. Consequently, you'll need a `Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>>` where `T` is the class representing the data. (In the example in the docs, the class representing the data is `Color`. You'll need something slightly more complex here, encapsulating the text and the image.)

Comment: Thank you very much @James_D. I have got it working to the point where I need to _"set a button cell"_. How exactly do I do this so that it is set to the exact layout that I would see in the dropdown list? The example they give is `.setButtonCell(cellFactory.call(null));` But where do I need to put this? cellFactory isn't a variable in the example they gave with <Color>. ..And do I need to change it from null?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so I've managed to work this out, thanks to @James_D 's very kind help!

This is for anyone who, like me, was slightly daunted by the example that was given in the Java documentation. *(Although, my description below is probably worse!!)*

---

So, I started by adding an `HBox` which was in the layout I wanted straight into the `ComboBox`... which is a **bad idea**!

So, before you go deleting everything you've done, save the `HBox` somewhere, and do the following:

**1**. Create a new class to hold your date (Image, and String) which will go into each cell. Make getters/setters to do this. I called mine `IconTextCell`.

**2**. Add the following code to the class where your `ComboBox` is located:

```
yourComboBox.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>>() {

    @Override public ListCell<T> call(ListView<T> p) {
        return new ListCell<T>() {
            Label name = new Label();
            Label icon = new Label();
            private final HBox cell;
            { 
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY); 
                cell = new HBox();

                //HERE, ADD YOUR PRE-MADE HBOX CODE

                name.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                icon.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                icon.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                HBox.setHgrow(icon, Priority.ALWAYS);
                cell.getChildren().add(icon);
                cell.getChildren().add(name);
            }

            @Override protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    name.setText(item.getLabel());
                    icon.setGraphic(item.getIcon());
                    setGraphic(cell);
                    //HERE IS WHERE YOU GET THE LABEL AND NAME
                }
           }
      };
  }
});
```

*You'll see that the main content is very similar to what I had already produced, so no code is lost.*
*Just replace "T" with your own class for representing a cell.*

**3**. This will display your icon and string in the list, but you need to to also be displayed in the button (the grey top selector part of the `combobox`, aka the `button`). Do do this, we need to add the following code:

```
class IconTextCellClass extends ListCell<T> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item != null) {
            setText(item.getLabel());
        }
    }
};

selectionBox.setButtonCell(new IconTextCellClass());
```

...and that's how I did it. I hope this helps - please compare this to my original post. The actual content (where I create the HBox etc) is obviously not generalised. You can make this as simple or as complex as you want.

Once again, thanks for your help! I hope this post helps others!